# tensorflow gpu медленно работает

Tags: нейронные-сети, cpu, gpu, tensorflow

обучаю нейронную сеть, для ускорения процесса решил направить обработку на GPU, но оказалось что в этом случае сеть обучается медленнее минимум аж в 2 раза (не привожу замеры т.к. разницу и так сильно видно "на глаз")

установил CUDA 9.0, cudnn-9.0, через pip установил tensorflow-gpu .

вот данные карты:

```
2018-05-23 22:18:33.882111: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 780 major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.006
pciBusID: 0000:22:00.0
totalMemory: 3.00GiB freeMemory: 2.47GiB
2018-05-23 22:18:33.885634: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-05-23 22:18:34.156250: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-05-23 22:18:34.158607: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-05-23 22:18:34.160023: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-05-23 22:18:34.161542: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2195 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 780, pci bus id: 0000:22:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
```

CPU - AMD ryzen 5 1600x, сеть оповещает что она может работать быстрее (т.е. видеокарта работает в 2 раза медленнее с учётом того что установленный tensorflow не поддерживает AVX2)

```
2018-05-23 22:17:08.490491: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

но GPU вроде как должен выдавать большую производительность, ошибок никаких не выскакивает и я не могу понять почему он так медленно работает.

что проверить, в какую сторону смотреть? или я всё сделал правильно и мой CPU в принципе работает быстрее видеокарты?

Comment: Там вроде требования к определенным версиям cuda есть. Верно?

Comment: @adrug, "GeForce GTX 780" вроде бы поддерживается...

Comment: Да я про cuda 9.0, она поддерживается?

Comment: @adrug, да, [это зависит от версий tensorflow, Cuda, Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14244)